# if-else logic simplification

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, logic, boolean-logic

I have two registers as follow,

```
HL(consecutive), H holds 8-bit, L holds 8-bit so HL is 16-bit register pair
DE(consecutive), D holds 8-bit, E holds 8-bit so DE is 16-bit register pair
```

I'm not able to compare `HL` and `DE` directly like `if(HL > DE)`. Instead I have to compare separately the registers as `H, L, D, E`. I construct if-else structure possibilities to know `if(HL > DE)`.

1.

```
if (l < e)
   if(h > d)
      do what I want
... if not checking other possibilities 2, 3
```

2.

```
if (l > e)
   if(h > d)
      do what I want
... if not checking other possibilities 1, 3
```

3.

```
if (h > d)
     do what I want
... if not checking other possibilities 1, 2
```

I'm not sure whether I do rightly. However, if so, can be three of them simplified?

Comment: Signed or unsigned ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust unsigned

Comment: Then Iłya Bursov's answer. `h > d or (h = d and l > e)`

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes sir, it works like a charm but I wonder by what the way used they are simplified. Could you say?

Comment: Your proposal is just overly complicated.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what do you mean? I only express that how do you get the simplification? What the method do you use?

Comment: Which simplification ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust the following one `h > d or (h = d and l > e)`

Comment: You can't make it simpler.

Comment: @YvesDaoust no you misunderstood me, I mean how did you achieve to obtain `h > d or (h = d and l > e)` from if-else statements in my question. What way did you apply? I'm asking if I run into the same problem again.

Comment: I didn't look at your statements, as I knew they were overly complicated.

Comment: @YvesDaoust so how do you say ilya's answer after my saying unsigned? Interesting.

Comment: I didn't need Ilya's answer, but it was there already. Comparing numbers isn't that difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two cases when unsigned hl > de:

1. `h > d`
2. `h == d AND l > e`

Comment: it works like a charm but I wonder by what the way used they are simplified. Could you say?

Comment: @snr I'm not sure that I understood question, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean how do you get the simplification? What the method do you use?

Comment: @snr I suppose it was [structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction)